# 2 x 1080Ti vs 1 x 2080Ti. So much difference?

Tags: 3d-view, gpu

This is my first post and new to blender, was following Blenderguru’s tutorial. I noticed that his quality in viewport rendered mode, is far superior than mine. Sharp shadows and the highlights are very close to final render, mine is just grainy. Andrew’s gpu : 1080Ti x 2, my gpu : 1 x 2080Ti.

[image]

Any thoughts guys?

What am I missing? i.e. missing gpu, add-on, tweak settings?

Appreciate

Answer (score 2):

The reason why his viewport rendered preview mode is so much closer to the final result is that BlenderGuru has set his *Viewport Sampling* to be much higher. Higher samples means less noise and lighting artifacts. Since he essentially has twice the computing power, he can afford to crank up the samples in the viewport much higher without dealing with too much lag.

You could probably also increase yours since you still have a 2080ti. In the second screenshot on the right-hand side, under *Sampling*, increase the value next to *Viewport*. Turn it up as high as you like, just take care not to crank it up so high such that the preview becomes too laggy.

Comment: Hi stphnl329, appreciate your input, i tried upping the sample, as high as 16,384 px for start pixel, but there's no change :( apparently, tweaking the viewport settings, only works for Eevee, there is only a slight change for cycles.

Comment: Looking closer, you can tell that BlenderGuru also only has 32 samples from the top left of his screen when he's moving the viewport camera around (it shows *Rendering Tracing Sample 1/32*), so yeah I guess that isn't it. However, if you look at the shadows in the center of his donut, you can see a considerable amount of noise still, so I guess its just the lighting at that specific frame.

Comment: However, if you look later in that video at 5:47, you can see that he's also got a considerable amount of noise in his render preview. Increasing the viewport samples *will* reduce the noise, but your computer will need to keep rendering those samples before you'll start noticing major quality improvements (take note of how quickly your the sample count in the top left is increasing)